# Import data from multiple excel file to SharePoint list using power automate

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, power-automate, excel-services, powerbi

I have more than 150 excel files which all have same information table to update their production from different location. my question is can I use Power Automate to import and consolidate all data in a list in SharePoint?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. There is an action available in power automate for it.

[image]

To access Excel with a dynamic path, you can refer this https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Automate-Community-Blog/Power-Automate-How-to-access-Excel-with-a-dynamic-path/ba-p/462763

You can create an array of locations in power automate and loop through it. I haven't implemented anything similar, so this is my suggestion.